# How to use a Database Generated Identity Key in Web Api OData

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata

I've managed to create number of readonly Web Api OData services following the tutorials here: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api. I'm therefore employing the ODataConventionModel builder to create the model from a set of entities (incidentally coming from a Telerik ORM). This all seems to work fine and I can happily issue queries, view the metadata and so forth on the service.

I've now tried to turn my attention to the other CRUD operations - firstly Create and have stumbled into a problem! Namely, the Post method fires correctly (CreateEntity) but the entity parameter is null - by doing a check against the ModelState.IsValid, it shows that the problem is a null ID (key) value. This is unsurprising because the database uses a Database Generated Identity for the ID column and therefore the ID would be created when the entity is saved into the database context.

I've therefore tried all sorts of ways of marking the ID column as database generated, but haven't managed to find anything. Strangely, I can't seem to find even one post of someone asking for this - surely I can't be the only one?!

I noted that when looking at the EF modelbuilder (for example here: http://forums.asp.net/t/1848984.aspx/1) there appears to be a means of affecting the model builder with a .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption property, but no similar option exists in the System.Web.Http.OData equivalent.

So the questions therefore are:

1. Is there a means of altering the model builder (or something else) so that the controller will accept the object and deserialize the entity even with a null key value?
2. If so, how can I do this?
3. If not, any suggestions as to other options?

I realise that I could potentially just populate the object with an (in this case) integer value from the client request, but this seems a) semantically wrong and b) won't necessarilly always be possible as a result of the client toolkit that might be used.

All help gratefully received!

Many thanks,

J.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a viewmodel for insert which does not contain the ID parameter. Use Automapper to map the properties of the incoming insert-model to your data entities.

The problem that you're having is that ID is a required attribute in your data model because it is your PK, except during insert, where it shouldn't be specified.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts Eric - this still seems like a workaround rather than a solution to me. While I acknowledge that this would work, it effectively forces creation of other methods rather than resolving the issue with the OData models that are automatically created by the ModelBuilder. Unless I've misunderstood your answer of course....

Comment: Not really a workaround at all. It's an insert ViewModel and is a very common practice in the MVC world. Your controller accepts an InsertEntity and returns a full Entity or just the ID. It ends up being very RESTful.

Comment: I thought one of the REST tenets is that a controller should use the same model throughout all its actions? This alone has caused me a lot of bother. It implies that callers should pass default values for database generated columns such as ids and created-datetimes, which is unacceptable for me.

Comment: @Beginner, REST doesn't mean that they all have to have the same model. It's just that all endpoints should operate on the same base type. It's quite common to have an InsertModel and an UpdateModel since some properties (like CreatedDateTime) aren't even allowed to be updated, etc.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, my database-generated key is a Guid.

As a work-around, in my TypeScript client code, I submit (via http POST) the object with an empty Guid like this:  Note: ErrorId is the key column.

```
    let elmahEntry: ELMAH_Error = {
        Application: 'PTUnconvCost',
        Host: this.serviceConfig.url,
        Message: message,
        User: that.userService.currentUserEmail,
        AllXml: `<info><![CDATA[\r\n\r\n${JSON.stringify(info || {})}\r\n\r\n]]></info>`,
        Sequence: 1,
        Source: source,
        StatusCode: 0,
        TimeUtc: new Date(Date.now()),
        Type: '',
        ErrorId: '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
    };
```

Then, in my WebApi OData controller, I check to see if the key is the empty guid, and if so, I replace it with a new Guid, like this:

```
    // POST: odata/ELMAH_Error
    public IHttpActionResult Post(ELMAH_Error eLMAH_Error)
    {
        if (eLMAH_Error.ErrorId == Guid.Empty)
        {
            eLMAH_Error.ErrorId = Guid.NewGuid();
        }

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        db.ELMAH_Error.Add(eLMAH_Error);

        try
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateException)
        {
            if (ELMAH_ErrorExists(eLMAH_Error.ErrorId))
            {
                return Conflict();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return Created(eLMAH_Error);
    }
```